# How to upgrade add_to_builtins function to django 1.9 and later

Tags: python, django

I need to upgrade an old project to django 1.11, and I found that the function `add_to_builtins` is removed in django 1.9. I wonder how can I achieve the same functionality.

The package is django-coffin and it seems like it hasn't been maintained for a while. Here (https://github.com/cdleary/coffin/blob/master/coffin/common.py) in line 114, it loads the django default templates as class instances and process it in line 70 here (https://github.com/cdleary/coffin/blob/master/coffin/template/library.py). After I removed the `add_to_builtins` function by adding them directly in to the settings.py file as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = (
    {
        'BACKEND': 'some backend',
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            ],
            'builtins': [
                'coffin.template.defaulttags',
                'coffin.template.defaultfilters',
                'coffin.templatetags.static',
            ],
        }
    },
)
```

I can get the default builtins as follows:

```
from django.template.engine import Engine
django_builtins = Engine.default_builtins
for lib in django_builtins:
    _load_lib(lib)
```

The problem is that the django_builtins return a list of strings, which cannot be called as an instance and get the tags in the line 70 described above. I wonder if there is a way to fix this, any advice is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into the django 1.8 and django 1.11 source code, I finally found the solution.

Basically, the builtins list is buried inside the Parse class so that you can't get it directly.

I found a hacky way to do it, which is to mimic how it was done in django 1.8

Here is the code:

```
from django.template.engine import Engine
from django.template.library import import_library
django_builtins = []
django_builtins_strings = Engine.default_builtins
for item in django_builtins_strings:
    django_builtins.append(import_library(item))
```

Basically, the django import_library function still exists, and I can call it directly.
The Engine class has the default builtin and it actually calls the import_library function internally. 
So what I did was to get the strings and make the builtins list manually by calling the django import_library function.